# Language support in VueJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, multilingual

Currently I am working on a SPA using vuejs and I need to add language support for that. We already have a language service where you can requests language ('en-us' & etc) and it will return language json (***200KB+ data set and getting all data at once will hit the performance badly***) object in below format:

```
"Texts": [
        {
            "Text": "Setup user",
            "TextId": 10000
        },
        {
            "Text": "SU",
            "TextId": 10001
        },
        {
            "Text": "Address",
            "TextId": 10002
        },
        {
            "Text": "Invoice date",
            "TextId": 10004
        },....]
```

In a prevoius jquery application, we developed language populating in way that you request language translation only for used keys(for that we used jquery)

This is how we did it: we added a data-key attribute to all the html elements which needs a translation and provided the key as value. Then using jquery we collected all requested keys in the app

```
$('*[data-key]').each...
```

and then posted the request.

**From this mechanism we could get the translations only for the used keys.**

I am kind of new to vuejs and trying to figureout how to do the same in vuejs. I really appreciate your help.

PS:
I can easily achieve this by adding key in two places (one in the request object and one in the place where I need the translation) in the application but I believe there should be another solution where you only add the key once.

Comment: Do you expect to make *one* call to get all the translations? Not all components in Vue are loaded at the same time.

Comment: Number of calls actually doesn't matter. Requirement is to get only relevant translations. Thanks for the quick reply btw.

Comment: Straightforward solution in my opinion can be the following: in each component set an array with phrases ids needed for this particular component's template. This is not harder than setting 'data-key' attributes everywhere. If you use Vuex (or another central state): create a state object to save all fetched phrases; in 'created' hook make a request to fetch those particular phrases, and concat fetched ones to the common set. In components use a getter to get phrases from Vuex; if a phrase doesn't exist return empty string for a moment. But in reality I'd check if multiple requests are better.

Comment: Check [vue-localize](https://github.com/vuedev-com/vue-localize) out.

Comment: Hello! could solve the problem? I can suggest you the [vue-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-i18n).

Comment: Also check this one: https://github.com/leonardovilarinho/vue-multilanguage